# ros_camera_info service not found for usb_cam

Tags: calibration, ros-groovy, stereo-calibration, camera, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I use 2 USB cameras for stereo vision with the usb_cam driver in ROS Groovy and I would like to calibrate them with the camera_calibration package. I start the cameras with the following launch file:

```
<launch>
  <group ns="stereo">
    <node name="left" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
        <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
        <param name="image_width" value="640" />
        <param name="image_height" value="480" />
        <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
        <param name="camera_frame_id" value="left" />
        <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>      
    </node>
    
    <node name="right" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
        <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video2" />
        <param name="image_width" value="640" />
        <param name="image_height" value="480" />
        <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
        <param name="camera_frame_id" value="right" />
        <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>      
    </node>
  </group>  
</launch>
```

they work nicely. Then I want to calibrate them with the following command:

```
 rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 9x7 --square 0.0053 right:=/stereo/right/image_raw left:=/stereo/left/image_raw left_camera:=/stereo/left right_camera:=/stereo/right --approximate=0.005
```

and it generates the following errors:

```
Waiting for service /stereo/left/set_camera_info ...
Service not found
Waiting for service /stereo/right/set_camera_info ...
Service not found
```

Why? How can I fix it?
I know I can use the the `--no-service-check` parameter and it works afterwards, but it won't commit then the calibration parameters to cameras. What is the proper way to do camera calibration with the usb_cam driver?

Running the calibration with the `--no-service-check` parameter works and results a `/tmp/calibrationdata.tar.gz` file which contains the `ost.txt` text file with the calibration parameters. But I don't know what to do with this data in order to use the stereo vision. Can anybody help me here?

**Update 1:**

the /stereo/left/camera_info do exists in my case and the `rostopic echo /stereo/left/camera_info` streams messages like this:

```
---
header: 
  seq: 1383
  stamp: 
    secs: 1368623369
    nsecs: 14836818
  frame_id: left
height: 480
width: 640
distortion_model: ''
D: []
K: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
R: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
P: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi: 
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: False
---
```

**Update 2:**

the `rosservice list` query results the following output:

```
/rosout/get_loggers
/rosout/set_logger_level
/stereo/left/get_loggers
/stereo/left/image_raw/compressed/set_parameters
/stereo/left/image_raw/compressedDepth/set_parameters
/stereo/left/image_raw/theora/set_parameters
/stereo/left/set_logger_level
/stereo/right/get_loggers
/stereo/right/image_raw/compressed/set_parameters
/stereo/right/image_raw/compressedDepth/set_parameters
/stereo/right/image_raw/theora/set_parameters
/stereo/right/set_logger_level
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62778/ros_camera_info-service-not-found-for-usb_cam/) by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-16**:
I don't see any code in that driver to publish the `set_camera_info` service. What does `rosservice list` print when the driver is running?

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-05-16**:
I am at home now, and I have here different USB cameras but everything else is the same, same laptop, same setup. I made a query `rosservice list` and I got the stuff that I just included above in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a bug in the driver to me.

It advertises `/left/set_camera_info` when it should provide `/stereo/left/set_camera_info`, and similarly for the right.

Possibly the driver is advertising an absolute name when it should be providing a relative name within the `/stereo` namespace. You can try running in the top-level namespace (without `/stereo`) to see if that works around the problem.

Why don't you [open an issue](https://github.com/bosch-ros-pkg/usb_cam/issues) with a link back to this question, so you don't have to repeat all the details?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-05-17**:
Thanks @Joq! Unfortunately there were some problems with the `rosservice list` output, so I update it. It seems that previously there were some remnant services after a crash from an other testrun with the uvc_cam driver. Now in the current output the set_camera_infos disappeared.